# When accessing a FAT32 partition in Ubuntu, does it get flagged for Windows to run chkdsk?

Tags: windows, ntfs, disk, partitioning, fat32

I have a Windows 10 computer.  I booted it up using an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live CD.  The hard drive has 3 partitions which were automatically mounted in Ubuntu - C and D drives which are NTFS partitions, and E drive which is a FAT32 partition.

I was clicking around in those 3 Windows partitions, but I was only viewing directory contents - I did not write anything to any of those partitions.  Then I told Ubuntu to shut down the computer.  Then I turned the computer back on and booted into Windows 10.  It immediately said "Scanning and repairing E:", which I think in Windows 10 means it's running a chkdsk.  It did not say anything about scanning/repairing the C or D drives.

I have rebooted my Windows 10 computer a ton of times, and this is the first time I've ever seen a "Scanning and repairing" message.

Looking around at various forums, I saw a couple people say that if you access a Windows partition in Ubuntu, Ubuntu will flag the partition for precautionary purposes so that chkdsk runs on it the next time Windows boots up.  But I have seen nothing definitive about this.  If this is true, then it is only true for FAT32 partitions, because I didn't see the "Scanning and repairing" message for the C or D drives which are NTFS.

I just want to make sure that the "Scanning and repairing E:" message was supposed to appear for precautionary purposes, and that it didn't appear because Ubuntu corrupted the partition.

Comment: Have you disabled fastboot in Windows? That usually makes the Windows (NTFS) partitions inaccessible or at best allowing read only.  I don't know if it's the same for FAT32 partitions. If not that would explain it: The other partitions were "protected" but a change was detected in the other. Fastboot is hibernation basically and it assumes no changes in the next boot.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I checked my BIOS and Fast Boot is unchecked.  So you think the NTFS partitions were read-only, and the FAT32 partition wasn't so Ubuntu changed something on it?

Comment: Fast boot is a windows option, not a bios one.  Make sure you unmount the partition in Ubuntu before rebooting and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @psusi Ah, the Windows option is called "fast startup", and it is enabled.  But based on [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953674) by Mars11, if you restart instead of shutting down, then Windows won't do the hibernation.  I'm pretty sure I restarted before booting into Ubuntu, so anything written to the partitions in Ubuntu would have stuck.  The question remains though - why did Ubuntu do something to the E partition that would cause Windows to run a chkdsk on it on the next bootup?

Comment: The most likely option is that you didn't manually unmount the partition, and Ubuntu did not automatically unmount the partition when you shut down, so it was left in a dirty state.  Manually unmount it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've found that Windows is very fond of using its Fast Startup feature. I've had to completely disable both it and the related Hibernate feature to get Windows to properly unmount partitions when shutting down *or rebooting.*

Comment: @psusi I just tried booting up with the Ubuntu CD a few times to see if I could reproduce the issue.  Each time I mounted the Windows partitions and did not unmount them before shutting down.  Each time the subsequent Windows bootup did not do a chkdsk, so I can't reproduce this anymore.  I'm not sure the problem had to do with not unmounting before shutting down anyway, because [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12768/72548) says that all drives are automatically unmounted during shutdown.

Comment: @pacoverflow, now that I re-read my previous message I see that my meaning was not clear.  They are *supposed* to be unmounted on shutdown, but there was probably a bug that prevented this.